# ssh: how to view docker-compose logs on remote machine more lively

Tags: logging, ssh, docker-compose, remote-server

I have an aws instance with docker compose running there

I want to have a look at the logs, i am trying

```
ssh -i "aws_key.pem" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx<<'ENDSSH'
cd PROJECT_FOLDER
docker-compose logs --no-color --tail=2000 webapp
ENDSSH
```

I can see the logs, but it the connection closes

How can i keep it live

Answer (score 0):

Following "[Docker Compose: From Local to Amazon ECS](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-from-local-to-amazon-ecs/)" from [Anca Iordache](https://github.com/aiordache), you might consider an alternative to SSH: [docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/), to [create an AWS context](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#create-aws-context) in which you can follow logs.

```sh
$ docker context create ecs myecscontext
? Create a Docker context using: AWS environment variables
Successfully created ecs context "myecscontext"

$ docker context use myecscontext
myecscontext

$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="*****"
$ export AWS_SECRET_KEY="******"

$ docker-compose logs --no-color --tail=2000 webapp
```

Comment: I will look into this, But anything with ssh

Comment: Would adding -t as an option to your SSH command help? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/133985/7490)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the `follow` option.

Try `docker compose logs --follow` or `docker compose logs -f`